# Why do anime don't have closing logos at the end of the series?

Tags: anime-production

In western TV programs, the show ends with a closing logo, usually one or two closing logos.  In anime, they end the show with a preview and no closing logos.  Why don't anime have closing logos at the end of a show?

Comment: They usually show the production companies' logos during the opening credits, rather than at the end of the closing credits. *Why* they do it this way round, I don't know.

Comment: I just noticed this when I remembered watching full episodes of anime that don't have closing logos at the end, anime rarely has opening logos before the opening credits.

Comment: Do you have examples of these "closing logos"?  Honestly it's been a solid half-decade since I watched anything western (mostly due to choice and not wanting to bother with an antenna/streaming package) and I'm drawing a complete blank here.

Comment: To be honest, I'm also not sure about "closing logos". Did you mean the title logo, or other logos like production studio, sponsorships, or anything else?

Comment: They likely mean these end title cards for the particular production companies involved, that appear after the credits of shows https://youtu.be/BC-eFU6OgxA

Answer (score 0):

They do (for similar purposes, but not in the same way), they are called "End Cards" and are typically used to adjust the timing of each episode to make sure they fit a certain amount of time. It's usually for television broadcasts and some streaming services might omit them (or at least used to). It's typically a commissioned pie of art by a (typically) well-known 3rd party artist/illustrator, artist associated with the production, or artist of the original work. Not all anime productions have them and it's said that SHAFT popularized the use of it, when they did *Tsukuyomi: Moon Phase*.

[image: Magical Girl Destroyers]